# What thread should callbacks occur on in Java?

Tags: java, callback

I'm developing a Java library that runs a scheduled task in a ScheduledExecutorService. If the user specifies callback(s), then after that task, those callback(s) will be invoked.

Right now I just have the scheduler thread invoking the callbacks. Should those callbacks execute in their own ExecutorService in their own thread pool?

Comment: It does't matter, so long as it's documented - the recipient then becomes responsible for managing it based on their needs and context

Comment: That makes sense. I've decided for now to have a separate ExcutorService for handling the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best approach would be to provide the client with both options: with an Executor specified for the callback and without it, similar to how it's done in [CompletableStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html):

```
public CompletionStage<Void> thenAcceptAsync(Consumer<? super T> action); // executes action on internal default executor

public CompletionStage<Void> thenAcceptAsync(Consumer<? super T> action, Executor executor); // executes action on provided executor
```

This way, the client can choose which approach is more convenient for their use case.

Comment: That makes sense for complete flexibility. For now, I'm going to have a separate ExecutorService for callbacks to execute on.